# How to avoid re-render when not change chekcbox value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Below is my code

```
function App() {
  const [learningLanguage, setLearningLanguage] = useState({
    chinese: false,
    english: false,
    korean: false,
    spanish: false,
    japanese: false,
  });

  const  handleLanguageChange = (e) => {
    const target = e.target;
    const checked = target.checked;
    const name = target.name;
    setLearningLanguage({
      ...learningLanguage,
      [name]: checked,
    });
  };


  return (
    <div className={style.container}>
        <div className={style.card}>
          <h3>Please Select a Language ?</h3>
          <div>
            {
              Object.keys(learningLanguage).map((v) => {
                return <CommonCheckBox key={v} type="checkbox" id={v} name={v} 
handleChange={handleLanguageChange} checked={learningLanguage[v]} title={v} />
              })
            }
      
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is CommonCheckBox  component

```
function CommonCheckBox(props) {
    console.log('=== re-render ===')
    return <label htmlFor={props.name} className={style.label}>
    <input
      type={props.type}
      id={props.id}
      name={props.name}
      onChange={props.handleChange}
      checked={props.checked}
    />
    {props.title}
  </label>
}

export default CommonCheckBox
```

This is is work find.
But my question is how to avoid re-render when checkbox is not change?

Answer (score 1):

```
export default React.memo(CommonCheckBox).
```

React has a concept of PureComponent which in react functional components is imparted using React.memo. This helps one avoid re-renders of a component unless a value in the component is changed. Read more about this : https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html

Comment: This is not working, you still have  five times "=== re-render ===" infos in console.